# Matrices - homogeneous system

Tags: matrices, homogeneous-equation

Hello I’m taking the course 18.02 multivariate calculus of MIT. I don’t understand the thinking behind the answer of a problem.

The question is (with Julia notation):

For what c-value(s) will $$\left(\begin{matrix}2& 1\\ 0 &-1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right) = c\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)$$ have a non-trivial solution? (Write it as a system of homogeneous equations)

The answer is:

(1):    $\left(\begin{matrix}(2-c)x+y\\(-1-c)y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$ has a non-trivial solution if

(2): $\left|\begin{matrix}(2-c)&1\\0&(-1-c)\end{matrix}\right|=0$ i.e., if:

(3):    $(2-c)(-1-c) = 0$ or $c=2, c=-1$

I don’t understand how we come from the question to (1) or (2). Which theorem is used?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: In (2), you mean $\left|\begin{matrix}(2-c)&1\\0&(-1-c)\end{matrix}\right|=0$ right?

Comment: yes thank you @John Doe. I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A\mathbf x = c\mathbf x\\
A\mathbf x - c\mathbf x = 0\\
A\mathbf x - cI\mathbf x = 0\\
(A\mathbf  - cI)\mathbf x = 0$

Either $\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$ (the trivial solution)
or $A - cI$ is singular, and $\det (A - cI) = 0$

Comment: @JohnDoe thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Doug M. Sorry for the maybe stupid question but what is I in your answer: Inverse?

Comment: $I$ is the Identity matrix.

Comment: ok thank you again @Doug M. But why does the fact of multiplying x by the identity matrix $I$ help? And shouldn't $A\mathbf x$ also be multiplied by $I$ in that case?

Comment: In order to factor out the vector $\mathbf x$ we need objects of the same type, i.e. $2\times 2$ matrices.  And since $I\mathbf x = \mathbf x$ this isn't really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

We  have (1), which is $$\left(\begin{matrix}(2-c)x+y\\(-1-c)y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$$
This can be rewritten as
$$\left(\begin{matrix}(2-c)&1\\0&(-1-c)\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$$
There are now two ways to understand why the determinant of this matrix must be zero:

(a) - Suppose it does not have zero determinant. Then the matrix is invertible, so you can multiply by its inverse on both sides of this equation. Then you would get $(x,y)=(0,0)$, which is not a non-trivial solution (which is what you are asked for). So our assumption that it has non-zero determinant must be false.

(b) - You are looking for a non-trivial vector multiplied by a matrix to give the zero vector. This vector must then be an eigenvector of this matrix, with eigenvalue $0$. The determinant of a matrix is the product of the eigenvalues of the matrix, so if we have a $0$ eigenvalue, then the determinant must also be zero.

Therefore we get (2) $$\left|\begin{matrix}(2-c)&1\\0&(-1-c)\end{matrix}\right|=0$$

Comment: Thank you @John Doe. I think I get your answer. Sorry for the basic question but how do you get from the question to (1)?

Comment: @ecjb $$\left(\begin{matrix}2& 1\\ 0 &-1\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right) = c\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}c&0\\0&c\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)\\\left(\left(\begin{matrix}2& 1\\ 0 &-1\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}c&0\\0&c\end{matrix}\right)\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right)\\\left(\begin{matrix}(2-c)&1\\0&(-1-c)\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The theorem behind is [Rouché–Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) which states that

> A system of linear equations with n variables has a solution if and only if the rank of its coefficient matrix $A$ is equal to the rank of its augmented matrix $[A|b]$.If there are solutions, they form an affine subspace of $\mathbb {R} ^{n}$ of dimension $n − rank(A)$.
>
> In particular:
>
> - if $n = rank(A)$, the solution is unique,
> - otherwise there is an infinite number of solutions.

In this case we are looking for no trivial solutions of $(A-cI)x=0$, that is for solutions with $x\neq 0$, and that require that $$rank(A)<n \iff \det(A-cI)=0$$